# How to embed long and complex sql queries into Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below VBA code that works successfully in getting data from SQL database to an Excel worksheet when I have to embed a simple query (e.g. `Select * from table1`), but this code isn't working and showing a

> Compile error: user-defined type not defined.

when I have complex and long queries:

```
 Sub ConnectSqlServer()

        Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim sConnString As String

        ' Create the connection string.
        sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=vrsqladhoc;" & _
                      "Initial Catalog=TACT_REV;" & _
                      "Integrated Security=SSPI;"


        ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        ' Open the connection and execute.
        conn.Open sConnString
        Set rs = conn.Execute("select distinct column1 from table1;")

        ' Check we have data.
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            ' Transfer result.
            Sheets(2).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        ' Close the recordset
            rs.Close
        Else
            MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
        End If

        End Sub
```

The long query I am intending to embed in the VBA code looks something like this:

```sql
    SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table1 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

    Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table2 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table3 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table4 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table5 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table6 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table7 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end

Union All

      SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type

    FROM table8 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end
```

Please let me know how the long SQL queries can be embedded into the VBA code without any errors.

Comment: "I am aware that the spacing of SQL queries has to be different in VBA" - what are you talking about?

Comment: I am saying I know spacing of sql queries has to be different in VBA, but I also acknowledged that I am not sure how that should be. What did you not understand in that ?

Comment: Again, I've no idea what you're talking about. As far as VBA is concerned, SQL queries are nothing but string literals, VBA doesn't know or care about SQL in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: What compile error are you getting specifically, and where's the code that *tries* to get this "long and complex query" into a string literal? Also have you considered making a *view* or *stored procedure* on the SQL Server instead of maintaining a complex query in a string literal, without syntax highlighting, intellisense, and any kind of validation?

Comment: I am getting user defined type - not defined error. Sorry I don't have authorization to create views or sprocs at this point of time

Comment: VBA doesn't understand SQL, VBA compiles VBA code. The query needs to be in a string.

Comment: If you want stringify the SQL into VBA it's brutal brute force for this long of a query. I'll provide an general answer below but there may be tons of caveats depending on your SQL below. The best solution is to follow @Mat'sMug advice and store as a procedure in the database you can call.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, your 3. comment sounds like an answer to me, especially the part about converting "VBA queries" into stored procedure or view at SQL Server side.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks Scott. Sorry I don't have authorization to create views or sprocs at this point of time. So if you can help me in stringfying the SQL query that would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @MaciejLos hmm, you're right. I actually had a draft when Scott posted his answer :)

Comment: You already got couple of great suggestions/answers. Another way to do this is to save the long sql in a text file, read it using FSO in VBA and use that sql content to open the recordset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stringify SQL into VBA do something like the below:

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when " & _
        "missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type" & _
        "FROM table1 cm " & _
        "inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2 " & _
        "WHERE cm.column3 = 'R' " & _
        "and cm.column4 = 3 " & _
        "group by case when " & _
        "missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end "

sql = sql & " UNION ALL "

sql = sql & " keep going like this ..."
```

You can do it in one statement if its short SQL and easy-to-read, but with long statements, you will run into continuation line (`_`) issues in VBA. That is why I broke it into several settings of `sql`.

This is brute force and not ideal solution, think nightmare to debug and maintain!

Best is to store in db directly as stored procedure and have excel vba call that.

Comment: instead of sproc I can also achieve the objective using view, right ?

Answer (score 6):

Exactly how you're building your connection string:

> ```
>     sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=vrsqladhoc;" & _
>                   "Initial Catalog=TACT_REV;" & _
>                   "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
> ```

By concatenating string literals.

Now, one problem you'll run into with such a long query, is that VBA will not let you make a *logical* line of code that spans much more than 10-15 *physical* lines of code. See, the above statement is one single *logical* line of code, but it spans 3 *physical* lines, which involves 2 *line continuation* tokens.

So you just do that:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when " & _
      " ..." & _
      " ..." & _
      " ..." & _
      "and so on"
```

And when the compiler starts complaining that there are too many line continuations, you just concatenate it with itself:

```
sql = sql & " rest of the " & _
      " ...query"
```

Obviously this is going to get very ugly, very fast. Fixing a bug in that query will be a nightmare. Maintaining that query will be a nightmare. Merely *looking* at that query will give you nightmares.

Regardless of the language, such complex queries **don't belong in source code**. They belong on the server, in a *view* or a *stored procedure*. If you can't create a view or stored procedure on the database, give your query to someone who can.

If there's absolutely no way to avoid it, then I'd warmly recommend you use a [`StringBuilder`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/23788) to do the string concatenations. The result will at least be much cleaner than a mess of interleaved line-continuated concatenations, and will perform better.

```
Dim sql As String
With New StringBuilder
    .Append "SELECT ..."
    .Append "..."
    .Append "..."
    .Append "..."
    .Append "..."
    .Append "..."
    sql = .ToString
End With
```

Side note: whatever you do, **never** concatenate user input into a SQL query. Parameterize it instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to write my SQL queries for embedding in Excel/VBA in Notepad++ and then save them as a simple .sql (text) file.  I have a script which, using .fso (FileSystemObject) reads in the contents of the file and uses that to form the query (the connection to my DBs are all boiler-plate).

When a file is then ready for deployment to the business I copy the entirety of the SQL query into a TextBox on a Worksheet, this can then be referenced by:

```
strSQL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL_Query").TextBoxes("SQL_Text").Text
```

The benefit of this is that all the indentation from Notepad++ remains in place.

The final stage is to ensure the Visible property of the Worksheet is set to .xlSheetVeryHidden and, of course, the code is password-protected.

Comment: I use something similar, which allows editing in Excel:  I create a range, concat the range while removing "-- to end of line" segments, then insert into sqlString

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy.  Just look out for word wrap!

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "Your_Server_Name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "Northwnd" ' Enter your  database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = " SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 "
    SQLStr = SQLStr & " FROM Orders Where Order ID = 100 " ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z500")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub



Sub Working2()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set con = New Connection
strConn = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True"

con.Open strConn

'Put a country name in Cell E1
Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.MyOrders '" & ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text & "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Text & "'")

'The total count of records is returned to Cell A5
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close

End Sub
```

Leave a space before and after each double quote.

So, for you, I think it should be something like this...

```
SQLStr = " SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type
    FROM table1 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end "
SQLStr = SQLStr & " Union All
    SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type
    FROM table2 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end "
SQLStr = SQLStr & " Union All
    SELECT Count(column1) as status_count, case when 
    missing_flag = 1 then ' Missing' else ' Available' end as status,'Name' as Document_Type
    FROM table3 cm
    inner join table2 md on md.column1 = cm.column2
    WHERE cm.column3 = 'R'
    and cm.column4 = 3
    group by case when 
    missing_flag1 = 1 then 'Missing' else 'Available' end "
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread I stumbled on, but I thought I would throw in a solution that I have found handy.

A solution I have found useful to this is storing the queries in a worksheet and then referencing the values (e.g. `sQuery = sheets("Queries").Range("A1").Value`). In completed projects, the spreadsheet containing the stored queries is hidden from normal view.

Using a standard text editor, you can write the query and then cut and paste it into a cell and it will appear as it did in the text editor. This makes it easy to read, doesn't clutter your code and makes it easy to change/update later if needed.

Here is an example I cut & pasted from one of my worksheets into this editor:

```sql
SELECT
       invoice_id,
       temp.invoice_number,
       temp.open_date,
       temp.close_date,
       product_id,
       description,
       line_total,
       taxable
   FROM
       lineitems
           INNER JOIN
       (SELECT
           invoice_id, invoice_number, open_date, close_date
       FROM
           invoices
       WHERE
           close_date BETWEEN [start_date] AND [end_date]) AS temp USING (invoice_id)
   WHERE
     taxable=1 OR product_id LIKE '%TAX%';
```

In the example above, I use the `replace()` function to replace the `[start_date]` and `[end_date]` parameters with correct values, before the query is executed.

In actual practice I use multiple columns in the sheet where the queries are stored. The first column contains a ref-name for the query, the second column contains the query and the third column contains a description and any additional comments/notes.

Using some creative functions (`GetStoredQuery()`, `PutStoredQuery()`, `ExecuteStoredQuery()`, etc.) this becomes very similar to using stored procedures in SQL, except your stored procedures are stored in your VB Project instead of the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to wrap long sql code in a procedure on the sql server part. Consequently you don't need to write long sql code in vba. The procedure can have parameters so you don't need to change anything in the sql code. Just call the procedure from vba using sqlcommand and that's it.

Comment: This seems more suitable as a comment rather than an answer. Please consider writing comments instead of answers if you have suggestions, or want to get clarification from the OP.

Comment: Do you mean my answer is not suitable because I'm not sure, if the author has posibility to create procedures at SQL Server part?

Comment: No @user5475314, I think you got me wrong. I meant to say that after reading your answer, I felt like you were suggesting, so, it'd have been more suitable if you had posted a comment. But in its current state too, there's nothing potentially wrong. Anyways, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I was bashing my head against the wall with the same problem. The easiest way to solve that is to save the complex code as a stored procedure on the database itself. After that you can simply write a VBA code to execute the said procedure. Far easier and less painful to maintain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).