# Filtering a Lookup Field Based on Another Field - Compile Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using an AfterUpdate() event to try to code a lookup on a 2nd combo box in Access.  I believe I have the syntax correct but on compile, I am getting an error stating Expected End of Statement.  The AfterUpdate event is:

```
Private Sub CompanyName_AfterUpdate()
    [cboCompanyName].RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    [cboInvID].RowSource = 
       "Select Inventory.InvID, Inventory.Product, 
               Inventory.[Product Description], Inventory.Qty, 
               Inventory.PricePerUnit, Inventory.CompanyName "

        FROM Inventory 
        INNER JOIN Artist 
           ON Inventory.CompanyName = Artist.CompanyName " &
       "Where Artist.CompanyName = ' " & cboCompanyName.value & " ' ";
End Sub
```

This is my first post so I need to provide any further details, I would appreciate the feedback.  Thank you.

Comment: What is your rfbms? This looks like VB or Access.

Comment: You need line concatenation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100808/3820271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed long and complex sql queries into Excel VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100470/how-to-embed-long-and-complex-sql-queries-into-excel-vba-code)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your problem, but can give you basic guidelines so you can debug your own code.

First try to make your code at least compile, so try something simple:

```
cboInvID].RowSource = "SELECT Inventory.InvID  FROM Inventory"
```

Once you know your parts are working next objective is make it work as intended.

Build your query and test it direct on the db

```
SELECT *
FROM Inventory 
INNER JOIN Artist 
  ON Inventory.CompanyName = Artist.CompanyName
Where Artist.CompanyName = 'Sony';
```

Once you have a working query instead of passing to the RowSource save it on a string so you can debug it

```
strSQL  = "SELECT *
           FROM Inventory 
           INNER JOIN Artist 
              ON Inventory.CompanyName = Artist.CompanyName
           WHERE Artist.CompanyName = 'Sony'";
cboInvID].RowSource = strSQL;
```

Finally, you go and add the input value.

```
strSQL  = "SELECT *
           FROM Inventory 
           INNER JOIN Artist 
              ON Inventory.CompanyName = Artist.CompanyName
           WHERE Artist.CompanyName = '" & cboCompanyName.value & " ' ";
cboInvID].RowSource = strSQL;
```

This allows you check if the strSQL is the correct one and allow you to detect any error sintaxis.

Now you have something working need also check how use parameter on your code, because **SQL INJECTION** is a big risk when using string concatenation.  But that depend on what lenguaje and db are you using.

Comment: This won't compile either, you can't use multi-line strings in VBA like this.

Comment: @Andre VBA wasnt even a tag when I wrote my answer. And again I just try offer basic guidelines to debug. If creating the string fail is easy to detect why. In this case the simple example on one line will work and as you suggest mutiline wont

Comment: Thank you for the suggested changes.  I'm relatively new to Access so could you please explain your comment about saving it on a string?  Are you suggesting not passing it to the RowSource in the manner I attempted?

Comment: I've been able to get it to compile but am getting an error stating "can't file field "|1" referred to in your expression.  Any recommendations.